# Prolog uncaught exception

Tags: functional-programming, prolog

I am trying to start with Prolog, but I am unable to compile the first example. I have tried to enter it interactively, and loading from file too.

```
cat factorial.pl 
factorial(0,1). 

factorial(N,F) :-  
    N>0, 
    N1 is N-1, 
    factorial(N1,F1), 
    F is N * F1.

| ?- ['factorial.pl'].
compiling /tmp/factorial.pl for byte code...
/tmp/factorial.pl compiled, 7 lines read - 813 bytes written, 2 ms

yes
| ?- factorial(4,X).
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,factorial/0),factorial/0)
```

Edit: I am getting the above problem with GNU prolog. SWI prolog works fine.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code. I tried this code in GNU Prolog version 1.4.4 and it worked fine. What version are you using? Either you have an old version or a bad installation.

Comment: Prolog top-Level (GNU Prolog) 1.4.5

Comment: I suspect there's something going on you're not showing. The error *error(existence_error(procedure,factorial/0),factorial/0)* indicates that you are attempting, somewhere, to call `factorial` without arguments. That's what `factorial/0` mean. Note that Prolog requires NO SPACE between the functor name and left parenthesis. Is what you are showing exactly what you did? I suspect perhaps not. If you tried, for instance, `factorial (4,X).` or if you corde really had `factorial (N1,F1)` then you would see that error.

Comment: To make sure I copy-pasted everything from here, same error.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. I copy/pasted from your question here and didn't get an error. The way I did it was: (1) ran `gprolog`, (2) entered `[user].`, (3) copy/pasted the code you show above, pressed Ctrl-D, (4) copy/pasted your query `factorial(4,X).` and pressed Enter. It ran fine. I also tried it this way: (1) entered `cat > factorial.pl`, (2) copy/pasted your code above, pressed Ctrl-D to create the source file, (3) ran `gprolog`, (4) entered `['factorial.pl'].` which succeeded, and (5) copy/pasted your query. It also ran fine.

Comment: Where did you get version 1.4.5 from? 1.4.4 is the latest version on sourceforge.net. Version 1.4.4 is also the latest according to the [GNU Prolog website](http://www.gprolog.org/#download).

Comment: Ubuntu 17.04, synaptic. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/zesty/+source/gprolog

Comment: I just built and installed gprolog 1.4.5 and see the same error you do. Version 1.4.5 seems to be broken. I don't understand why 1.4.5, if it's official, would  appear on an Ubuntu site but not on the GNU Prolog website. I would recommend installing 1.4.4. That's what the GNU Prolog site refers to as the "last stable version".

Comment: Thank you! Since I am totally new to Prolog I thought that I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Evidently, this was [reported as a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gprolog/+bug/1711346). Just click the ["bugs" link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gprolog/+bug/1711346) on the site you referenced.